# ASP.Net AJax MaskedEdit Currency mask broken

Tags: asp.net, ajax

The demo on the main ASP.net AJax page @ http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx shows the problem I am experiencing.

When I tab into the "Enter a Number" textbox and enter 1.25, it shows up as $1,000,025.00.  I would expect this to show as "$*,*__,__1.25".  I've read a number of threads on this but nothing indicating if this is a bug/issue/problem and/or how to make this control work as published.

Also, if I blank the text, the format mask still shows up in the textbox and validation fails even when the ClearMaskOnLostFocus=True.

I am working in VS2012/VB, .Net 4.5, Ajax Toolkit 4.5.7.1005 (latest).  I would have anticipated these control being fully mature and ready to use, so I am assuming I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called AutoComplete.

Set `AutoComplete` Property to `false` inside `MaskedEditExtender`.

It will give you the desired result you needed.